# How to remove NA columns from a combined data frame, when the data frame returns 18 variables against original 9

Tags: dataframe, dplyr

**I have following dataframe:**
head(ps_knk_alldata)

```
  **ID_frame**    ** TimeStamp**        ** MAC**   **ID** **RSSI** **Vendor**   **cod** **sync**   **MeshliumID**
1        1 2019-05-23 06:45:34 e6aa4f2224ee98e98 <NA>  -82                  Unknown    SmartPhone    0 1.914211e+13
2        2 2019-05-23 06:45:34 f7af897c07bf765a9 <NA>  -88                  Unknown    SmartPhone    0 1.914211e+13
3        3 2019-05-23 06:45:34 f9e35363525228634 <NA>  -85                  Unknown        Laptop    0 1.914211e+13
4        4 2019-05-23 06:46:13 24cb3474f61a53bac <NA>  -90 Bluegiga Technologies OY Uncategorized    0 1.914211e+13
5        5 2019-05-23 06:46:13 e6aa4f2224ee98e98 <NA>  -83                  Unknown    SmartPhone    0 1.914211e+13
6        6 2019-05-23 06:46:13 f7af897c07bf765a9 <NA>  -90                  Unknown    SmartPhone    0 1.914211e+13
  X347650 X05.03.2021.11.28 X48.01.C5.51.D4.D4 ...4 X.85 Unknown SmartPhone X1 X1.91421E.13
1      NA              <NA>               <NA>   NA   NA    <NA>       <NA> NA           NA
2      NA              <NA>               <NA>   NA   NA    <NA>       <NA> NA           NA
3      NA              <NA>               <NA>   NA   NA    <NA>       <NA> NA           NA
4      NA              <NA>               <NA>   NA   NA    <NA>       <NA> NA           NA
5      NA              <NA>               <NA>   NA   NA    <NA>       <NA> NA           NA
6      NA              <NA>               <NA>   NA   NA    <NA>       <NA> NA           NA
```

I have used following  to filter and get the error as mentioned below. Any answer?

```
psknk_all_filtered <- ps_knk_alldata %>%
+   select(where(not_all_na))
```

**code_returns**
Error in `instrument_base_errors()`:
! object 'not_all_na' not found
Caused by error in `is_function()`:
! object 'not_all_na' not found
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear, can you add some more info on what you are doing to get this `dataframe`, and what you want (currently title does not match question)

Comment: I hve device to capture data on road about Bluetooth devices. The data is received in 9 column format.

Comment: I have collected data daywise and in morning and evening slot every day. I want to combine all files as one single dataframe. Filter them further. When I combined the data using following code, I get additional columns, ranging from 3 to 9, ie. 12 to 18 columns in all. Col 10 to 18 are all NA. ```psknkfiles_evening<- list.files(path = path.files, pattern = "*PSKNK_EVENING.csv")%>%
  lapply(read_csv)```
```ps_knk_alldata_evening <-ldply(psknkfiles_evening, data.frame)```

Comment: As of now, I could manage the combined data, by selecting only the required columns. But I want that the NA columns should not be there in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, I could manage the combined data, by selecting only the required columns. But I want that the NA columns should not be there in the first place.

```
psknk_all_filtered_evening <- ps_knk_alldata[c(1:3,5:9)]
```

Now I have the observaions with 8 columns only. I left out the ID column, which was also NA.